# How do I convert Python POST data to JSON?

Tags: python, arrays, json, google-app-engine

I have the following code in Python:

```
def post(self):
    example = self.request.get("example")
    other = self.request.get("other")
```

How do I get all post data if unknown? I'm very new to Python but something along the lines of:

```
def post(self):
    array = self.request.get()
    myJSON = MagicArrayToJson(array)
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    self.response.write(myJSON)
```

Comment: You must specify what framework you're using, as it is not obvious.  My best guess so far is that you're using webapp2, but I would prefer not to guess.  https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/request.html states that the request has a few attributes that should be relevant to your question, such as `self.request.body`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may depend on the framework you use. But i suppose that there all have pretty same notation like `self.request.data` or `self.request.body` for post request.

Try `self.request.data` like this

```
def post(self):
    data = self.request.data

    # If data is in querystring, convert it to dict
    # urlparse lib is convenient for this

    myJSON = MagicArrayToJson(array)
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'
    self.response.write(myJSON)
```